# How to unselect a UITableViewCell after you have done some action using didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Currently I do some work inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate and noticed that my row is still "selected" after I come back to the view controller later.

How can I unselect this row inside the delegate itself?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //do logic and ... it remains selected in the view?
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 37):

Typically, you want to deselect the row when the view controller appears again:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```

That's what `UITableViewController` does implicitly, and animating the deselection process after the view controller appears again is a helpful hint to the user as to which cell they selected previously.

Comment: I think it's better to use `viewWillAppear:` instead so that the user doesn't briefly see the row selected